# Operand should contain 1 column(s) when trying to update one column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I have a `table2` which has a composite primary key built from two columns, one of which is a foreign key from another table called `table1`, and the other is called `position`.

The table has a third column which is a foreign key from `table3` and I want to update it if I come across a duplicate key of (`table1_id` and `position`). But instead, I get an error mentioned in the title. Here is the table schema for `table2`.

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `table1_id` int NOT NULL,
  `table3_id` int NOT NULL,
  `position` smallint NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table1_id`,`position`),
  KEY `table1_id` (`table1_id`),
  KEY `table3_id` (`table3_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table1_id_1` FOREIGN KEY (`table1_id`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table3_id` FOREIGN KEY (`table3_id`) REFERENCES `table3` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3
```

This is the table that I am trying to update. The error "Operand should contain 1 column(s)" occurs when I try to do "INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" statement which will update table3_id.

I tried the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO `table2`
    (`table1_id`, `position`, `table3_id`)
VALUES
    (3275027, 1, 5711)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `table3_id` = VALUES(`table3_id`)
```

A record with `table1_id` = 3275027 and `position` = 1 already exists, I just want to change the `table3_id` but it won't let me.

I expect the record with a unique composite primary key (3275027, 1) which is (`table1_id`, `position`) to update the third column `table3_id` from one value to `5711`.

I searched so much to find the answer and explanation for this, but I just couldn't eventually find a proper answer.

EDIT 1:

I have also tried to update the column manually with:

```
UPDATE table2 SET `table3_id` = 5711 WHERE `table1_id` = 3275027 AND position = 1;
```

but the same error occurs.

Comment: The published code works fine however the comma at the end of the insert is suspicious and you should check triggers. https://dbfiddle.uk/3aW214Ye

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry, i forgot to remove it, i have it removed, it is not due to the comma. Just edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Did you look at the link in my comment? There is nothing wrong with the published code.. and did you check triggers as suggested?

Comment: Hey @P.Salmon after 2 days of debugging, finally found out that i was missing a CONCAT keyword to concatenate two strings in db. That was happening in a trigger indeed. So thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I found out that i had two string needed to be concatenated put in parentheses without the "CONCAT" keyword to indicate calling the concat() function. That was happening in a trigger after the update.